# Java 8 method references for multiple statements in streams

Tags: java, lambda

`list.stream().forEach(e -> method(e))` can be converted to `list.stream().forEach(this::method)`

Similarly can we convert `list.stream().forEach(e -> { method1(e); method2(e);});`  using method references expressions. Big apologies if you don't understand question. I am using mobile app first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.

The point of Method references in Java is to abstract (syntaxically) a lambda expression. Since `forEach` consumes a function that takes 1 element of type specified by the parent stream, there is no syntax sugar for double application using method references.

Answer (score 1):

Even I'm not sure that this answer is wanted by you,

How about changing the method to static one in that class?